# SonarQube-compliant solution, increment cell value

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using Apache POI to create a excel form a Java POJO class.

The POJO has 65 fields which needs to be populated while creating a POJO.

One way I figured out was -

```
int i = 0;
hssfRow.createCell(i++).setCellValue(POJO.getField1());
hssfRow.createCell(i++).setCellValue(POJO.getField2());
hssfRow.createCell(i++).setCellValue(POJO.getField3());
.....
hssfRow.createCell(i++).setCellValue(POJO.getField65());
```

The drawback of the above approach is SonarQube says it is non compliant with the following reason

> Extract this increment or decrement operator into a dedicated
>   statement

The first question is why is it not advised to use `i++` here?

Also, is it advisable to declare constant from 1 to 65 in a separate Constant class and use it instead of `i++` (i.e. `hssfRow.createCell(Constant.ONE)`)?

And is there any alternative to this solution which is compliant and is a better approach?

Comment: I never understood what tools like `SonarQube` are good for. Because this are the kind of questions and code "improvements" they lead to. @Parth Manaktala: The message means, the `i++` should not be **in** `hssfRow.createCell(i++).setCellValue(POJO.getField1());`. `SonarQube` is the opinion that `hssfRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(POJO.getField1()); i++;` would be "better".

Comment: @AxelRichter sometimes they can be picky, but they are still just tools; only as good as you configure them.  They can call out things that you might miss, and you can always tell the tool that it's OK (unless management doesn't understand and wants blind strict adherence).  I have appreciated it's callouts for code duplication and certain cyclomatic issues.

Comment: @zero298 "... unless management doesn't understand and wants blind strict adherence": Exactly this. The management hires no programmers but code writers (or copy/paste guys) because it then relies on such tools that then will "improve" the badly written code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you can mark it as a false positive. The [stated reasons](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-881) for the issue are

- It can significantly impair the readability of the code.
- It introduces additional side effects into a statement, with the potential for undefined behavior.
- It is safer to use these operators in isolation from any other arithmetic operators.

Given the circumstances of your current code, I'd say they are invalid. The code is perfectly readable as it is and there's no undefined behavior possible and I don't see any safety concern there.

Comment: Even i was thinking the same, just curious if there is another library/approach that might be better

Answer (score 2):

I could be like this:

```
private static final Map<Integer, Function<POJO, TypeOfCellValue>> cellDataProviders = new HashMap<>(); 
static{
    cellDataProviders.put(1, POJO -> POJO.getField1());
    cellDataProviders.put(2, POJO -> POJO.getField2());
   ...
}
```

And use in code:

```
IntStream.range(1, cellDataProviders.size()).foreach( i -> hssfRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(cellDataProviders.get(i).apply(POJO)));
```

or with use of traditional for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cellDataProviders.size(); i++){
     hssfRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(cellDataProviders.get(i).apply(POJO));
}
```

the mapping from POJO to cell has been separated from the data population code.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a false positive you can use `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S...")` or `//NOSONAR`:

```
//NOSONAR
hssfRow.createCell(i++).setCellValue(POJO.getField1());
//NOSONAR
hssfRow.createCell(i++).setCellValue(POJO.getField2());
//NOSONAR
hssfRow.createCell(i++).setCellValue(POJO.getField3());
...
```

However then it is more clear to slavely change the code to:

```
hssfRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(POJO.getField1()); ++i;
hssfRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(POJO.getField2()); ++i;
hssfRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(POJO.getField3()); ++i;
...
```

Does not hurt.

---

***Playtime***

One could hide the index using a vararg method.
Assuming the POJO object variable is `pojo` and its class `Pojo`.

```
fillCells(hssfRow, pojo,
                Pojo::getField1,
                Pojo::getField2,
                p -> createDateCellValue(p.getField2()),
                Pojo::getField4,
                Pojo::getField5,
                p -> f(pojo),
                Pojo::getField7):

void fillCells(Row hssfRow, Pojo pojo, Function<Pojo, CellValue>... cellProviders) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cellProviders.length; ++i) {
        hssfRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(cellProviders[i].apply(pojo));
    }
}
```

This is not as flexible, but would remove some repetitive `hssfRow.createCell`.

Comment: *"However then it is more clear to slavely change the code to"* IMHO that's debatable. Those trailing `i++` are not that visible if you don't know they're there. Having them inside the statement makes them jump out. But, as I said, that's just my opinion :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca And they will not be aligned. At the line beginning would be somewhat better. On  a new line probably most regular. I'll still play a bit with my answer.